# Distributing lat long points equally within state boundary (USA) using Python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude

Looking to distribute points equally like the picture below within the boundaries of a given state such as California or Texas and then get those lat/long points as a csv or txt file. A way to do this using Python would be ideal but not necessary.

I have tried this and it doesn't distribute points evenly near edges:

```
def lat_long_loop(top_left, bottom_right, spacing):
    # Function uses bottom_right and top_left coordinates to create and return a list of equally spaced points
    # every "spacing" miles.
    # this code will NOT work if provided coordinates outside of USA/Canada/Mexico given how latitude/longitude works
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="Grid-Search")
    name_var = "point"
    lat_list = []
    long_list = []
    bottom_lat = bottom_right[0]
    bottom_long = abs(bottom_right[1])
    top_lat = top_left[0]
    top_long = abs(top_left[1])
    lat_dist = inverse_haversine(bottom_right, spacing, Direction.NORTH, unit=Unit.MILES)[0] - bottom_lat
    long_dist = abs((inverse_haversine(bottom_right, spacing, Direction.WEST, unit=Unit.MILES))[1]) - bottom_long

    while bottom_lat < top_lat:
        lat_list.append(round(bottom_lat, 5))
        bottom_lat += lat_dist
    while bottom_long < top_long:
        long_list.append(round(-bottom_long, 5))
        bottom_long += long_dist

    coordLIST = itertools.product(lat_list, long_list)
    print(type(coordLIST))
    for x in coordLIST:
        print(x)
        location = geolocator.reverse(x)
        if location.raw['address']['state'] == 'Minnesota':
            kml.newpoint(name=name_var, coords=[(x[1], x[0])])

    kml.save("searchpoints.kml")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, it *does* distribute evenly near the edges -- It just that the edges are uneven. You can convert the outer polygon border to line, densify, then convert the lines to points, but then you need to buffer inward by at least 1/2  the interval to avoid the opposite issue.